# XML conversion with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document and XSLT style sheet to change up how it displays. Right now I just want the XSLT document to make "Hello World!" show up when the XML document is run, but I am just getting a display of the XML document on the web page.

Here is the XML document (trial Doc.xml):

```
<?xml-styelsheet type="text/xsl" href="trialDoc.xsl"?>

<people>
    <person gender="M">
    <firstName>Sam</firstName>
    <lastName>McAllister</lastName>
    <age>25</age>
    </person>
    <person gender="F">
    <firstName>Kris</firstName>
    <lastName>Paolini</lastName>
    <age>24</age>
    </person>
    <person gender="M">
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
    <lastName>Turring</lastName>
    <age>19</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

And here is my XSL Document (trialDoc.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">
    Hello World!
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your XML has a typo; you probably wanted

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trialDoc.xsl"?>
```

Then, your XSL should produce XML tree - enclose your output with some XML structure with single node at the top:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, instruct the XSL processor to generate text output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    Hello World!
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was about to say, I found that misspelling and it worked the way I wanted it too. I was having it generate text output. Thanks for the sharp eye.